# jquery accordion jump when clicked with HASH sigh

Tags: jquery

below is my simple accordion code. it has an uncertain jump once  clicked, like when HASH tag is clicked the page scroll to top.. tried adding e.preventDefault(); but didnt help.. regards

PS : the editor asks me to add more details, I wonder what more details I can provide, if its only to add text and the editor think it has enough details then its ok I will write a few more sentences, but I still think it wants me to add more content, let me try now//

```
jQuery('.toggle-content').each(function() {       
  $(this).css('height', $(this).height());
  if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('open')){
    jQuery(this).hide();
  } else
    jQuery(this).show();
});

jQuery("h4.toggle").click(function(){      
  if(jQuery(this).parents('.accordian').length >=1){
    var accordian = jQuery(this).parents('.accordian');

    if(jQuery(this).hasClass('active')){
      jQuery(accordian).find('h4.toggle').removeClass('active');
      jQuery(accordian).find(".toggle-content").slideUp();
    } else {
      jQuery(accordian).find('h4.toggle').removeClass('active');
      jQuery(accordian).find(".toggle-content").slideUp();

      jQuery(this).addClass('active');
      jQuery(this).next(".toggle-content").slideToggle();
    }
  } else {
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass('active')){
      jQuery(this).removeClass("active");
    }else{
      jQuery(this).addClass("active");
    }
  }
});

jQuery("h4.toggle").click(function(){    
  if(!jQuery(this).parents('.accordian').length >=1){
    jQuery(this).next(".toggle-content").slideToggle();
  }
});
```

and here is the HTML..

```
    <div class="accordian">
      <h4 class="toggle active">
        <a href="#"><span class="arrow"></span>Toggle 1 Heading</a>
      </h4>
      <div style="display: block;" class="toggle-content open">
        toggle 1 data...
      </div>

      <h4 class="toggle">
        <a href="#" style="border-bottom:0 !important;"><span class="arrow"></span>Toggle 2 heading</a>
      </h4>
      <div style="display: none;" class="toggle-content">
        toggle 2 content..
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where's your `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Hi Felix, as I said I tried adding it but it didnt work, I added it under this line : jQuery("h4.toggle").click(function(){... thanks

Comment: I aslo added this..

     $("a[href^=#]").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); });

but it creates jumps in toggle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your href attributes from `href="#"` to this: `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Comment: this helped in another way.. nevertheless good to know more things.. cheers